# Fill retweet with javascript instructions

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm facing an issue. I try to complete the comment field ("abc") of a retweet with DevTools.

[image: Twitter screen]

With my keyboard, it's easy... From console, it's another story, I achieved to find the comment area. But when I fill it, the new value isn't correctly interpreted...

I use for example :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr')[0].children[0].textContent = "abcdef"
```

But, this doesn't trigger the function which update the characters counter, I think this is why I don't succeed. 
I have also try to do :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr')[0].children[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key':'a'}))
```

But this doesn't work either.

Does anyone know how I can achieve a fill of this field ?

Thanks you

Comment: Lurkers: Just FYI, the element isn't an `input` or `textarea`, it's a `span`.

Comment: FWIW, I think it would be more reliable to find the element using `document.querySelector(".public-DraftStyleDefault-block span[data-text=true]")`. No idea what event Twitter is looking for to update the char counter, though.